# Sharing GlobalProtect VPN from Windows with a Mac

Tags: windows, networking, mac, vpn, shared-access

I am doing contract work for a corporate client who issued me a Windows-based company laptop, but the project I am working on needs a Mac. I have a personal Mac but I can't get the VPN working on my Mac to do my work. I have been granted admin rights on the Windows machine to do whatever is needed.

How can I share the GlobalProtect VPN on the Windows laptop with my personal Mac?

I imagine I can set up some kind of proxy or LAN between the two machines.

Comment: Is the connection for the two computers by wifi or ethernet? If wifi, does the Windows computer have a second network adapter? Can your router connect to this VPN?